# SQL Server: Convert Between UTC and Local Time Precisely

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, datetime, utc

I have a few columns in an SQL server 2008 R2 database that i need to convert from local time (the time zone the sql server is in) to UTC.

I have seen quite a few similar questions on StackOverflow, but the answers all fail to work correctly with daylight saving time, they only take into account the current difference and offset the date.

Comment: Do you have to deal with times from during DST transitions (where two UTC values may be a valid result for a single local time)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could not find any way at all doing this using T-SQL alone. I solved it using SQL CLR:

```
public static class DateTimeFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
    public static DateTime? ToLocalTime(DateTime? dateTime)
    {
        if (dateTime == null) return null;
        return dateTime.Value.ToLocalTime();
    }

    [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
    public static DateTime? ToUniversalTime(DateTime? dateTime)
    {
        if (dateTime == null) return null;
        return dateTime.Value.ToUniversalTime();
    }
}
```

And the following registration script:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ToLocalTime(@dateTime DATETIME2) RETURNS DATETIME2 AS EXTERNAL NAME AssemblyName.[AssemblyName.DateTimeFunctions].ToLocalTime; 
GO
CREATE FUNCTION ToUniversalTime(@dateTime DATETIME2) RETURNS DATETIME2 AS EXTERNAL NAME AssemblyName.[AssemblyName.DateTimeFunctions].ToUniversalTime;
```

It is a shame to be forced to go to such effort to convert to and from UTC time.

Note, that these functions interpret *local time* as whatever is local to the server. It is recommended to have clients and servers set to the same time zone to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your input. In my case it was not something I needed to do more than once, it was part of an upgrade to the database where local time was used and i ended up just creating a standalone application to do the upgrade. But i have chosen to accept this as an answer because it deserves it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    DECLARE @convertedUTC datetime, @convertedLocal datetime
    SELECT DATEADD(
                    HOUR,                                    -- Add a number of hours equal to
                    DateDiff(HOUR, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), -- the difference of UTC-MyTime
                    GetDate()                                -- to MyTime
                    )

    SELECT @convertedUTC = DATEADD(HOUR,DateDiff(HOUR, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()),GetDate()) --Assign the above to a var

    SELECT DATEADD(
                    HOUR,                                    -- Add a number of hours equal to
                    DateDiff(HOUR, GETUTCDATE(),GETDATE()), -- the difference of MyTime-UTC
                    @convertedUTC                           -- to MyTime
                    )

    SELECT @convertedLocal = DATEADD(HOUR,DateDiff(HOUR, GETUTCDATE(),GETDATE()),GetDate()) --Assign the above to a var


    /* Do our converted dates match the real dates? */
    DECLARE @realUTC datetime = (SELECT GETUTCDATE())
    DECLARE @realLocal datetime = (SELECT GetDate())

    SELECT 'REAL:', @realUTC AS 'UTC', @realLocal AS 'Local'
    UNION
    SELECT 'CONVERTED:', @convertedUTC AS 'UTC', @convertedLocal AS 'Local'
```