# How do you call an instance method on BCL type from T-SQL without uploading a full SQLCLR assembly?

Tags: c#, t-sql, datetime, sqlclr, datetimeoffset

I have a datetimeoffset column in a table with varying TZ offsets in the rows.  I'd like to run them all through the [ToLocalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tolocaltime.aspx) method on the BCL type System.DateTimeOffset (due to Daylight Saving, I can't just use the [SWITCHOFFSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx) function).  The 'clr enabled' is already reconfigured.

The 'brute force' approach appears to be creating a static class with a static method, something like:

```
public static class DateTimeUtils
{
    [SqlFunction]
    public static DateTimeOffset ToLocalTimeZone(DateTimeOffset input)
    {
        return input.ToLocalTime();
    }
}
```

Is there any simpler route that would allow calling the BCL type/method without having to create an assembly in the database just for this?

I was hoping I'd be able to just call a method off of the SQL type, but no such luck.  Trying something like this:

```
DECLARE @foo datetimeoffset = getdate()

select [datetimeoffset]::ToLocalTime(@foo)
```

... gives

```
Msg 258, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Cannot call methods on datetimeoffset.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. I came to this conclusion after researching this a lot. Here is my solution to the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11063348/122718

Comment: Seems like such a shame to have to create an assembly just to call the BCL method that's clearly already sitting within the running SQLCLR.  Ah, well.  Thanks!