# SQL SERVER Convert UTC DATETIME to local date time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the column CreatedDateTime as shown below :

```
[CREATED_DATE_TIME] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE()
```

When I am retrieving the created date time, it is giving me datetime value in UTC, but I want to show the datetime value in local time.

How can this be achieved?

Looking forward to your answers and thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're prepared to use SQL CLR, the answer to this question might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063313/sql-server-convert-between-utc-and-local-time-precisely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below

— Convert a UTC Time to a Local Time

```
    DECLARE @UTCDate datetime
    DECLARE @LocalDate datetime
    DECLARE @TimeDiff int
```

— Figure out the time difference between UTC and Local time

```
   SET @UTCDate = GETUTCDATE()
   SET @LocalDate = GETDATE()
   SET @TimeDiff = DATEDIFF(hh, @UTCDate, @LocalDate)

— Convert UTC to local time
DECLARE @DateYouWantToConvert datetime
DECLARE @ConvertedLocalTime datetime

SET @DateYouWantToConvert = '4/25/2007 18:00'
SET @ConvertedLocalTime = DATEADD(hh, @TimeDiff, @DateYouWantToConvert)

— Check Results
PRINT @ConvertedLocalTime
```

Comment: Will this handle Daylight savings time also ?